# Best way to evaluate "value1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM value2" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, where-clause, sql-null

Does SQL Server have an operator equivalent to the Ansi SQL operators : IS DISTINCT FROM / IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?

I know I can replace :

```
value1 is not distinct from value2
```

with :

```
(value1 = value2) or (value1 is null and value2 is null)
```

or :

```
coalesce(value1, -1) = coalesce(value2, -1)
```

But these options will prevent the engine to use an index, so does SQL Server have an specific operator to check this comparison ?.

Thank you.

Comment: The first rewrite is correct and does not *generally* prevent the use of an index; that would depend on the further context of your query and what you've indexed. Comparing `COALESCE`d values does, so avoiding that is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, it does @HABO. I wanted to avoid it, because it's very verbose. But looks like there is no way around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not implement the `null`-safe operator, unlike other databases such as Postgres (wich suports the standard `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator), or MySQL (that has an extension operator called `<=>`).

So you are basically stucked with the following construct:

```
(value1 = value2) or (value1 is null and value2 is null)
```